# Show one numeric value for group of rows with same id when group of rows contain boolean data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing Node js app as a practice and I'm using an existing SQL Server database (trying to rewrite the existing .NET frontend that uses same database but lacking reporting flexibility).

I need to query "survey" table consisting of (guid, questionTag and value). I don't know why this table is designed like this, but I can't change it.

```
guid     question   value
----------------------------
 1         q1_1     false
 1         q1_2     true
 1         q1_3     false
 1         q2_1     false
 1         q2_2     false
 1         q2_3     true
...
```

The `guid` column is a reference to another table which holds info avout the user that filled the survey.

`value` is coming from an HTML form and represents a radio-button that user selected. User is asked two questions each with 3 possibilties.

I would like the end result of a query to group "q1_X" rows with same guid and "translate" their boolean values to one number - 1,2 or 3 depending on where "true" value is:

```
guid     question   value
---------------------------
 1          q1        2
 1          q2        3
```

Comment: Add some more difficult digit values as well, like q10_1, q1_11, q22_33.

Comment: @jarlh, I suppose you suggested testing with various values. I've already tested given example and it covers all possible variations of characters as long as there is only one "_" as separator the code is wokring OK. The values behind "_" represent user feedback and will never go over 5, either way there will be only one "true" row, so it doesn't really matter hom many rows with the same ID I have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need string functions, like [`left()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [`right()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`charindex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select 
  guid,
  left(question, charindex('_', question) - 1) question,
  right(question, len(question) - charindex('_', question)) value
from tablename  
where value = 'true'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad44679ebb9fb540421398d884121b47).
Results:

```
> guid | question | value
> ---: | :------- | :----
>    1 | q1       | 2    
>    1 | q2       | 3
```

Comment: Does exactly what I've asked. I just need more time to figure out how "true" becomes a correct number :)

Comment: I figured out the "right" part (where "true", take the right portion after "_" as value) :) Now, this solution looks so obvious and simple, and I don't mind "brute force" string manipulation...Thanks again!